# ViewWithTag causing problems with UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

[I followed this tutorial to create a UICollectionView.](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-uicollectionview-tutorial/) I copied their code with no problem, however when I tried it, it crashes

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    gridImages = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [gridImages addObject: @"test.jpg"];
    [gridImages addObject: @"test.jpg"];
    [gridImages addObject: @"test.jpg"];
    [gridImages addObject: @"test.jpg"];
    [gridImages addObject: @"test.jpg"];

}


- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return gridImages.count;
}


- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";

    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UIImageView *gridImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];

    gridImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[gridImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    return cell;
}
```

The crash is at this line:

```
 UIImageView *gridImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
```

and if I change the viewwithtag to like 99 or 101, it works, but the collection view as just a box, not the test.jpg image. What exactly is viewwithtag?

crash:

```
[UICollectionViewCell setImage:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1659b300'
```

Any idea what's going on?

EDIT: Sorry, the tag 100 is the tag associated with my UIImageView of the collectionview in storyboard. Still crashing though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd have to guess you set the 100 tag on the UICollectionViewCell itself, not the UIImageView inside of it.  Or both views have the same tag set.  viewWithTag will return the first view it finds with that tag, so you want to make them unique.  Did you possibly set the tag on the entire cell by accident first, then go set it on the image view while forgetting to remove it from the cell?  Any UIView subclass can have a tag, so you need to be careful as to which view is selected before you set its tag.

The crash is because the viewWithTag: method is returning a UICollectionViewCell instance, and it doesn't implement the setImage: method you are calling on it (via the "gridImageView.image = ..." line).

Comment: Ah. That was the problem. I first set the tag on the entire cell, and forgot to change it. I always wonder how people guess this sort of stuff. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To add to the accepted answer, the method `viewWithTag:` searches first the receiver, and then all its subviews for comparing the tag. So if the receiver had the tag specified, it will be returned.
And it is clear from the exception, that the `setImage:` method is being called on UICollectionViewCell and not UIImageView